# Scrape <head> with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to scrape the head from a webpage with Node.JS but I can't figure out how. I can access to all the body thanks to cheerio like this :

```
request(webUrl, function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        //Getting all the links 'a' from the webpage
        $('a').each(function(){

            //Getting the href attribute from the 'a' link
            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            //We keep the link only if it is the same root (in order to avoid the 'undefined' links and the subdomains or outside links (like social media links))
            if(url != undefined && url[0] == '/') {

                //We add the domain name to the url we got in order to have the full 
                url = websiteUrl + url;
                urls.push(url);
            }

        });
        console.log(urls);
    }
});
```

But impossible to get the head with this method. I tried this but it gives me only the body scripts for example, and not the ones in the header :

```
request(webUrl, function(err, resp, body){
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        $('script').each(function(){

            //Getting the href attribute from the 'a' link
            var url = $(this).attr('src');
            console.log(url);

            if(url != undefined) {


                wowo.push(url);
            }

        });
        console.log(wowo);
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me on this please ? :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look at the `htmlparser2` library ( cheerio uses it internally).](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2)

[Here is a show of it being used live.](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/20b0e251d73d640209308d110e08c98e/0afe773f9baeb1d8347e7bb8bb15dfaafb52eeb9)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, even if I try to use parse5 or htmlparser2, I only have this kind of results : `{ nodeName: '#document',
  mode: 'no-quirks',
  childNodes:
   [ { nodeName: '#documentType',
       name: 'html',
       publicId: null,
       systemId: null,
       parentNode: [Circular] },
     { nodeName: 'html',
       tagName: 'html',
       attrs: [Object],
       namespaceURI: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
       childNodes: [Object],
       parentNode: [Circular] } ] }`

And I don't have the full website, only the top. That's weird